# Shoot a point from another point

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, point, direction

How do I shoot a point directly north 3,000 feet from the corner of a polygon in ArcGIS Pro in WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)?

I start by going to Edit --> Create and choose Point at End of Line in the Create Features window. Then I click on the polygon corner, right-click and choose Direction/Distance. I think it's the Horizontal QB measurement that is throwing me off. I input 0 and then 3,000 feet in Distance and leave Pitch blank, but it shoots a line east.

Comment: Lots of ways, but exact details depend on the spatial reference in which you are working. Please [Edit] the Question to specify details.

Comment: Uh-oh. Distance is useless in Web Mercator, so it doesn't really matter what you do -- the result is going to be very wrong. You need to reproject into a spatial reference with meaningful coordinates, perform the translation, then deproject back to 3857 (at which point it will look bizarre, but be correct).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you have a workflow for that?

Comment: That *was* the workflow.

Comment: Ok 3857 is Web Mercator I see.

Answer (score -1):

I believe I may have figured it out. 00-00-00-1 is north, 90-00-00-1 is east, 180-00-00-1 is south, and 270-00-00-1 is west. It doesn't seem to when I just input 0, 90, 180, 270 and when I change the quadrant I get weird shots. If anyone knows a better, quicker way I'd appreciate an explanation.